# I have a requirement to convert color into Hexadecimal code in Java. I have color available in Java class like Red, Green, Anthracite

Tags: java, colors, hex

I have a requirement to convert color into Hexadecimal code in Java. I have color available in Java class like  Red, Green, Anthracite . I need to convert it into Hex code and return back to JSP.

Comment: provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I saw a method String.format("#%06x", color.getRGB() & 0x00FFFFFF) somewhere. But I did not get how can I use the existing color available in java class and can change it

Answer (score 0):

There are different way for your question
You can use `your_color.getRGB()` for get rgb 
and use `Integer.toHexString(your_color.getRGB())` return string

```
String hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(your_color.getRGB()).substring(2);
```

substring for don't select alpha

Comment: "your_color " is available with type String. Do I need to typecast it ?

Comment: @VARSHA your_color is type Color class

Comment: The color available in my java class is of Type String. How can I typecast string  into Color?

Comment: @VARSHA Color.decode("#FFFFFF"); method parameter is string

Comment: I used Color color = Color.decode(string); and getting Number Format Exception

Comment: Can you hekp on this. I tried try {
    Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField("yellow");
    color = (Color)field.get(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    color = null; // Not defined
}  But it is also not working